# Bash script that counts the word frequency

Tags: bash, shell

I have a file like this:

```
Today the a the a day
Hello today
```

I want to count the word frequency in the file with a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -A hashmap
cat words.txt | while read line
do
    IFS=' ' read -r -a l <<< "$line"
    for s in "${l[@]}"
    do
        if [ ${hashmap[$s]+abc} ]
        then
            let hashmap[$s]=${hashmap[$s]}+1
        else
            hashmap+=([$s]=0)
        fi
    done
    echo ${#hashmap[@]}
    #print 4(the length of the associated array )
done
#Weird! It seems that hashmap(associated array) goes out scope!
echo ${#hashmap[@]}
#print 0
for k in ${!hashmap[*]}
do
        printf "%s\t%s\n" $k ${hashmap[$k]}
done
```

Could you tell me Why it outputs nothing?

Comment: Thank you! I know how to fix it and what is the problem. The pipe opened a subprocess!

Comment: Just use a {} the group all the while until the end!

Comment: This might help: [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/74329)